# UIButton not showing on simulator when view's class is TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, scrollview

I have this weird problem where the buttons on the simulator or my iPhone are not showing when the class of the view's set to TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

When the view's class is set to UIView (default) it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this post](http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-drop-in-universal-solution-for-moving-text-fields-out-of-the-way-of-the-keyboard/) for instructions.

> For non-UITableViewControllers, use it as-is by dropping the TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView source files into your project, popping a UIScrollView into your view controller’s xib, setting the class to TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView, and putting all your controls within that scroll view.
>
> To use it with UITableViewController, pop the TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView source files in, and just make your UITableView a TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView in the xib — everything should be taken care of.

Are you using it with or without a `UITableViewController`?  Make sure you've embedded the button in your `UIScrollView`.  The site linked above also has a sample project you could reference for more help.